# Correct way to have multiple threads execute a single task

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, executorservice, scheduledexecutorservice

I am trying to execute a single function `foo` on an interval, and MULTIPLE times per interval.

The way I am currently doing it is by creating a service with a `newScheduledThreadPool` of whatever is specified (let's say 5 for this example). So the scheduled thread pool will be instantiated with a pool of 5.

Would this be the correct way to go about it?

Currently is executing the function 5 times at every interval (put a print statement in the function and seeing it print out 5 times every interval), but wanted to check if this is the right approach for this use case.

```
    service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(threadPoolSize, runnable -> {
        Thread t = new Thread(runnable, "Test");
        t.setDaemon(true);
        return t;
    });

     this.start();
    }

    void start() {
        long initialDelay = frequencySecs + ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(frequencySecs);
        for (int i = 0; i < threadPoolSize; i++) {
            service.scheduleAtFixedRate(this::foo, initialDelay, frequencySecs, MILLISECONDS);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want a randomize initial delay and a daemon thread, then this would be the right approach. You could also just use a TimerTask for this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your function's context and purpose is cause you didn't mention enough, depending on the context, you may have some problems with multiple threads in parallel like synchronization issues. But if your context needs not synchronization you can use multiple threads that executing same function.

This implementation would be much simpler if you do not need real parallelisation:

```java
private int scheduleCount = 0; // Global to the class

//...

private void foo(int executionCount) {
    System.out.println(String.format("Schedule times %d, execution times %d", scheduleCount, i));
}

//...

Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(()-> {
    scheduleCount++;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        foo(i);
    }
}, 300, 300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Here is the output log:

```
I/System.out: Schedule times 1, execution times 1
I/System.out: Schedule times 1, execution times 2
I/System.out: Schedule times 1, execution times 3
I/System.out: Schedule times 1, execution times 4
I/System.out: Schedule times 1, execution times 5
I/System.out: Schedule times 2, execution times 1
I/System.out: Schedule times 2, execution times 2
I/System.out: Schedule times 2, execution times 3
I/System.out: Schedule times 2, execution times 4
I/System.out: Schedule times 2, execution times 5
I/System.out: Schedule times 3, execution times 1
I/System.out: Schedule times 3, execution times 2
I/System.out: Schedule times 3, execution times 3
I/System.out: Schedule times 3, execution times 4
I/System.out: Schedule times 3, execution times 5
I/System.out: Schedule times 4, execution times 1
I/System.out: Schedule times 4, execution times 2
I/System.out: Schedule times 4, execution times 3
I/System.out: Schedule times 4, execution times 4
I/System.out: Schedule times 4, execution times 5
```

*Note that you may need a handle to scheduled executor service so that you can shut it down when it is no more needed.*

Comment: context is that i'm receiving messages in an SQS queue at a large TPS. Synchronization is not needed. but I want to poll more messages per second as the processing of the message is quick.

Comment: In this case I would recommend you to use a single threaded ScheduledExecutor service to schedule execution period, and one multi-threaded work stealing thread pool to execute the functions independently and parallely. See https://www.baeldung.com/java-work-stealing